# В коде есть ссылка. Как узнать, сколько раз человек по ней перешел?

Tags: python, windows, email

```py
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header import Header
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

sender_mail = "glu********@gmail.com"
sender_password = "********"

target_mail = str (input ("ВВедите свой имеил : "))

subject = " test mail "
msg = MIMEMultipart()
#от кого
msg ["From"] = sender_mail
#кому
msg ["To"] = target_mail
#ответ на письмо  :
msg.add_header ("reply-to",sender_mail)

mailsender = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
mailsender.starttls()
mailsender.login(sender_mail,sender_password)

mail_subject = "test mail "
mail_body_text = " текст текстового письма"

mail_body_html = "<html><head><body><a href='http://lavrynenko.com'>проверка ссылки</a></body></head></html>"

msg = MIMEText(mail_body_html,"html","utf-8")
msg["Subject"] = Header(mail_subject, "utf-8")
mailsender.sendmail (sender_mail , target_mail , msg.as_string())

mailsender.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы приводите фрагмент кода на питончике, который отправляет письмо с встроенной ссылкой.

Пускай этот код выполняется на Вашем домашнем ПК.

Отлично. Письмо ушло. пока его никто не читал.

Вот письмо пришло к пользователю. Он открывает его в почтовом клиенте. Возможно, это браузер. А может быть, и нет. Но, предположим, он нажал на ссылку.

Тогда почтовый клиент запустит браузер на компьютере пользователя и откроет в нём сайт, ссылка на который была в письме.

Заметьте, что в этом процессе не участвует ни Ваш компьютер, ни Ваша программа.

Как же посчитать переходы?

В тот момент, когда пользователь открыл сайт в браузере, его браузер послал запрос на сайт, ссылка на который была в письме. И сайт ему ответил. при этом он записал запрос в свой лог-файл.

Именно по анализу этого лог - файла и можно определить, что на сайт кто то зашел.

Усложнение этой идеи позволит для каждого письма сгенерировать уникальную ссылку вида `<html><head><body><a href='http://lavrynenko.com/?id=1234'>проверка ссылки</a></body></head></html>`, где цифры 1234 генерируются для каждого письма отдельно.

Тогда в логах будет видно, из какого именно письма перешли на сайт.

Еще можно в письмо встраивать однопиксельные картинки, которые загружаются с сайта - тогда будет видно, кто письмо ОТКРЫЛ, даже если он не нажимал на ссылку.

Правда, это всё уже очень известные фокусы. Спросите у спамеров - у них таких фокусов вагон и маленькая тележка.

Но суть проста: из программы, которую Вы привели - никак. Нужно использовать другие средства.

Comment: А я могу например переиграть этот код с ссылкой и подключить базу данных ,и например ,что бы туда вписывался еще и имеил?

Comment: проблема в том, что событие "клик по ссылке" происходит вне Вашего компьютера и программы. Это происходит уже на том компьютере, на котором пользователь открывает письмо. И там происходит взаимодействие между его браузером и сайтом. Вам нужно подсчитывать кликнутые ссылки на САЙТЕ. Это уже несколько другая история. Можете попробовать опубликовать исправленный вопрос, но я советую сначала "нарисовать на бумажке" происходящие процессы- возможно, картина прояснится.

Comment: Простая аналогия - вы рассовываете по всем соседским почтовым ящикам в подъезде листовки с такой же ссылкой. Как узнать, сколько раз её введут в браузере? Кроме как на сайте/сервере - никак.